# UITextField converts non-breaking spaces to spaces?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

It seems UITextFields convert all [non-breaking spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (nbsp, U+00A0) to [spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_character) (U+0020).  This causes problems for the editing of locale specific numbers.  For instance, in the French/France locale, the non-breaking space separates 1 and % to form "1 %".  However, since the UITextField converts the separator character to a space, the locale aware NSNumberFormatter is unable to parse the locale string and convert it to a number.

The following code snippet illustrates this problem.

```
NSLocale *fr_FR = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr_FR"] autorelease];

NSNumberFormatter *percentageFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[percentageFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[percentageFormatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:TRUE];
[percentageFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle];
[percentageFormatter setLocale:fr_FR];

NSDecimalNumber *one = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.01"];

// will be "1 %" where the separator character is a nbsp (this is correct)
NSString *percentage = [percentageFormatter stringFromNumber:one];

UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
textField.text = percentage;

// will be "1 %" where the separator character is a space (this is wrong)
NSString *textFieldValue = textField2.text;

// returns an indeterminate value: may throw an exception, may return nil, etc
// this should return the number 0.01
NSNumber *percentageNumber = [percentageFormatter numberFromString:textFieldValue];
```

**My question: How do I prevent the UITextField from converting non-breaking spaces to spaces?**

I understand the work arounds I can employ to hack this so that it works if I'm in a locale that uses non-breaking spaces.  However, if there is property/behavior of the UITextField that I'm not aware of to preserve nbsp, I'd like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this feature doesn't exist. How about opening a bug report for the iPhone?

Comment: That was my suspicion as well...I figured I'd try asking here first before logging a bug to Apple.

Comment: Bug 6413923 has been logged to Apple.