# UITextView text property returns " " if "&nbsp;" is typed in by the user?

Tags: iphone, sdk, uitextview, html-entities

Does anyone have a solution to this?  I did some google-ing and came up with zilch.  I have no idea why a UITextView would replace `&nbsp;` with a space, but it is indeed happening.

It is easy to duplicate - type the non breaking space code I placed in the title of this question into a UITextView, and then look at the text property, you'll see a space.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: And the worst thing is that it doesn't even convert it to a non-breaking space. It just becomes a normal space character.

Answer (score 2):

You are out of luck. This is most likely a bug, and it seems it has been filed with Apple.
See post [UITextField converts non-breaking spaces to spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327283/uitextfield-converts-non-breaking-spaces-to-spaces).

As a workaround you can use the delegate method `textViewDidChange:` to catch the keyboard input to keep track of any `&nbsp;` occurrences and then react accordingly.

Cheers,
Sascha